# Knockout observable property contains function code

Tags: knockout.js, typescript

First of all, I'm using Knockout and TypeScript.

Given the following source code:

```
class LookupEditorVM {
    lookups: KnockoutObservableArray<LookupVM>;
    selected: KnockoutObservable<LookupVM>;
    baseURL: string = "/Admin/Lookup/";

    constructor() {
        this.lookups = ko.observableArray<LookupVM>([]);
        this.selected = ko.observable<LookupVM>();

        $.getJSON(this.baseURL + "ListLookups", (data) => {
            ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this.lookups);
        });

        this.selected.subscribe(() => {
            this.getListItems();
        });
    }

    getListItems() {
        $.getJSON(this.baseURL + "GetLookupItems/" + this.selected().ID, (data) => {
            ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this.selected().LookupItems);
        });
    }
}

class LookupVM {
    ID: number;
    Name: string;
    DisplayName: string;
    Description: string;
    LookupItems: KnockoutObservableArray<LookupItemVM>;

    constructor(ID?: number, Name?: string, DisplayName?: string, Description?: string) {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.Name = Name;
        this.DisplayName = DisplayName;
        this.Description = Description;
        this.LookupItems = ko.observableArray([]);
    }
}
```

The following function is giving me fits:

```
getListItems() {
    $.getJSON(this.baseURL + "GetLookupItems/" + this.selected().ID, (data) => {
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this.selected().LookupItems);
    });
}
```

The ID property of selected is coming up with the text of some knockout function. It should be a number. I've also tried passing the ID into getListItems as a number type, but it still comes through as a function text.

What am I missing?

**Update**

I've changed this.selected().ID to this.selected().ID() to take into account the observable. I've also taken the suggestion of Mark and changed the LookupVM properties to be observables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Knockout Mapping plug-in will create all of the properties in the objects it creates as observables (which is the "function" you are seeing for the value), by default.  So, this line:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this.lookups);
```

creates an array of `LookupVM` where each of the properties are observable.  The TypeScript types specified in the class definition are ignored, since they do not exist at run time.

This is probably what you want - in which case just change your properties to be observables, e.g.

```
class LookupVM {
    ID: KnockoutObservable<number>;
    Name: KnockoutObservable<string>;
    etc.
```

and use `this.selected().ID()` in your other ajax call.

Alternatively, you could to tell the Mapping plug-in to copy the properties instead of creating observables:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {"copy":["ID","Name","DisplayName","Description"]}, this.lookups);
```

I'm not sure how you want to handle the `LookupItems` property in this case - you may want to check the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html).

Comment: That doesn't seem to help, but it definitely seems like better code. I just noticed that if I do this.selected().ID() in the immediate window, I get the proper results.

Comment: @kettch What did you change?  You should use `this.selected().ID()` in the code, as noted in my answer, since ID is an observable.

Comment: I changed the LookupVM properties to observables as you suggested, and changed this.selected().ID to this.selected().ID(). It still returns the observable instead of the value.

Comment: nvm, I think the browser was caching weirdly. It appears to be working fine now. Thanks!

Comment: @kettch Phew, that's a relief, otherwise it would have been really strange!  I can't count the number of times the browser cache has bitten me!